# Write a MIPS assembly language version of the following C code segment

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mips32

This is the C code segment:

```
int A[50], B[50];    
for (i=1; i < 50; i++) {      
  A[i] = A[i] + B[i-1] / A[i-1];    
}
```

I wrote the Code in assembly language I don't know where to add the `/ A[i-1]` part in my code:
Here is my Assembly Code i worte
UPDATED CODE:

```
     li $t0, 1 # Starting index of i
     li $t5, 100 # Loop bound
loop:
     lw $t1, 0($a1) # Load A[i-1]
     lw $t2, 4($a2) # Load B[i]
     add $t3, $t1, $t2 # A[i-1] + B[i]
     sw $t3, 4($a1) # A[i] = A[i-1] + B[i]
     addi $a1,$a1, 4 # Go to i+1
     addi $a2,$a2, 4 # Go to i+1
     addi $t0,$t0, 1 # Increment index variable
     bne $t0, $t5, loop # Compare with Loop Bound

halt:
     nop
```

If You guys could help me with this it would be great, like guide me in on how to do it I am new to this languages so its a bit hard to read a textbook follow its examples.

Comment: What is causing you problem? Have you read through the instruction set reference? Did you find the instruction for division? Do you understand where it puts the result? Do you see how to access it? Also do you know about operator precedence?

Comment: @Jester Error in D:\Downloads\mips6.asm line 8 column 6: "addi": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: addi $t1,$t2,-100

Comment: @Jester do i add  'addi $a1, a1, 4' ?

Comment: That's an unrelated error. Read how `addi` works. Of course the error message also tells you. You need to specify the destination for the result. E.g. you want `addi $a1, $a1, 4` to do `$a1 = $a1 + 4`.

Comment: @Jester I have fixed the errors now when i run it says "Error in D:\Downloads\mips6.asm line 4: Runtime exception at 0x00400008: address out of range 0x00000000" Why ?

Comment: @Jester ^^^ ???

Comment: `A[i-1] + B[i]` doesn't appear in the C anywhere, it's `A[i] += B[i-1]` that you need.  (But actually you need to divide *before* adding anyway).  MIPS has a `div` instruction.  [MIPS: Integer Multiplication and Division](//stackoverflow.com/q/16050338)

Comment: @PeterCordes where in my code would i add the div ??

Comment: After the load(s), before the add, obviously, because that's when you have the necessary inputs in registers.  Read the linked question to find out how to use it.

Comment: Also why is the loop bound `100` if you have 50 items...

Comment: @Jester nice catch

Comment: @PeterCordes sure ill try reading it and edit now

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't get the form like i dont know how to add it :(